# Nested Level Tab is not working HTML CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have  here added my code and demo link [Click Here](https://codepen.io/jprakashrpm/pen/QZrGxV)

Here are some list items there each list contain some action button to "edit,delete"
on mouse over only visible the action button and as per WCAG i want show action button by pressing tab to next next button and list.

I can't able select the action button when press using tab.

I want to select the list first then select the action button

same thing for every list

```css
.action {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
}

ul li:focus .action {
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover .action {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>This is admin menu list</p>

<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 1
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 2
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 3
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 4
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 5
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you <kbd>Tab</kbd>, focus moves to the button, leaving the `li`. Your CSS rules are such that the `li` losing focus will hide the buttons' container.

You could use [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) instead of `:focus` to resolve this. It applies to an element that either has focus, or *contains* an element that has focus.

Unfortunately, its not supported by IE or Edge, but I believe it's the only solution that doesn't involve JavaScript.

```css
.action {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
}

ul li:focus-within .action {
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover .action {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>This is admin menu list</p>

<ul>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 1
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 2
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 3
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 4
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
  <li tabindex="0">Collection 5
    <div class="action"><button>add</button><button>edit</button></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obligatory Can-I-Use : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within ..... no love for MS users

Comment: @JonP Seems that way. Also, you may be aware, but all MDN links have support tables at the bottom :) That said though, I think caniuse is a bit more readable/informational.

Comment: I often forget about the compatibility tables on MDN, mainly because they're buried at the bottom of the page!

Comment: yes actually i tried after posted this question :focus-within in chrome browser  it's working fine i think chrome was recently given this option ":focus-within" any way thanks lot.